# Unable to write json data to file in c++

Tags: c++, json

I have a json data which I want to write to a json file in c++. I am using [nlohmann json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) and below is the code:

```
using nlohmann::json;

std::ofstream output_file("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\output.json");

json outJson;

std::time_t now = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
std::string created(30, '\0');
std::strftime(&created[0], created.size(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", std::localtime(&now));

outJson["Created"] = created;
outJson["DataId"] = "T-452";
outJson["Type"] = "UserData";

output_file << outJson;
```

But nothing is getting saved in `output.json`.

Comment: That’s a strange output filename—was it opened successfully?

Comment: @DavisHerring How do I check if file was opened or not.?

Comment: @DavisHerring Or do you mean I need to open the file first like output_file.open()

Comment: Does your default user account have access to write into $C:\Program Files (x86)$? Sometimes windows machines need Admin access by default to write into $Program Files (x86)$ or $Program Files$. If that's the case, you must manually grant write permission to your user account.

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction Yes it has all the rights it needs to open/save a file in C. I have tested this with another cpp code wiriting a sample text to example.txt file and it works fine but only with this json, it do not write anything.

Comment: Try $output_file << outJson.dump(); output_file.flush(); output_file.close()$ at the end of the program? Does it work?

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction Looks like I was not closing the file and thus it was not saving. I did: `output_file << outJson; output_file.close();` and it worked fine without dump or flush. I just wanted to know how can I include `indent=4` and `ensure_ascii=False`.

Comment: @RandomPerfectHashFunction with `output_file << outJson.dump(4)`, it is saving as expected. Thanks. If you can post answer I will accept it.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: @SAndrew: You can just convert the stream to `bool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit serialisation and calling `close()` before exiting should do the trick here.

```
output_file << outJson.dump(4);
output_file.close();
```

Comment: What happens without the `.dump(4)`?

Comment: The code works functionally the same without $dump(4)$.  It is included since the questioner asked to pretty print the JSON output with 4 space indentation.

Comment: Then what does “explicit serialization” mean?  What you have is otherwise the same as in the question, and `.close()` is automatic on destruction.

Comment: Implicit serialisation is when the compiler calls dump() implicitly from the operator overload mechanism. Explicit serialisation is the user explicitly calling dump(). I am aware of close() being called during object destruction, but the OC posted the question since that exactly was not happening on his machine. My comments in his question hinted him to modify his code as shown in the answer and it worked for him. I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.